# Android ListView displays nothing but doesn't crash

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-adapter

I followed all the steps from various sources for getting listviews to work but my one 
   doesn't seem to display anything. This list view code(shown below) is activated with a tab fragment manager I won't put that here as to not bog you all down with code as there's a lot here already. It is most likely a problem with the ListFragment itself but I suppose it could be the adapter.

What happens is nothing gets displayed at all just the searchview that I have put in the main xml layout. I can switch freely between tabs with no crashes but just nothing displays in any of my listviews. I have another list which is a friends list(not included in this code snippet) and that uses a generic view holder interface and that one does not work either which suggests the problem is most likely in my ListFragment but I just can't pinpoint it. Any help is appreciated and I hope some can learn something from this, Thank you.

This is my adapter for the settings category list

```
package codeblox.com.listfragmentexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import codblox.com.listfragmentexample.R;

public class SettingsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Settings.SettingsCategories>
{
private final Activity context;
String[] text;
ArrayList<Settings.SettingsCategories> itemsCopy;

class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView txt;
    public CheckBox state;
    public ImageView settingImg;
    public EditText input;
    public ToggleButton toggle;
    public Button settingInfo; // click it to show what the setting does
}

public SettingsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Settings.SettingsCategories> items)
{
    super(context, R.layout.settings_category_row, items);
    this.context = (Activity) context;
    this.itemsCopy = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    int viewType = this.getItemViewType(position);

    if(convertView == null)
     {
     // inflate the GridView item layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings_category_row, parent, false);
     // initialize the view holder
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.settingImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.settingCategoryImg);
        holder.txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.settingCategoryName);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
 // recycle the already inflated view
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // fill data
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    String s = getItem(position).toString();
    holder.txt.setText(itemsCopy.get(position).getSettingText());
    holder.settingImg.setImageResource(itemsCopy.get(position).getImgResId());

    return convertView;
 }
}
```

This is my list fragment

```
package codeblox.com.listfragmentexample
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import codeblox.com.listfragmentexample.R;


public class Settings extends ListFragment implements View.OnLongClickListener
{

private ListView settingsList;
private ArrayList<SettingsCategories> mItems;

private ArrayAdapter<SettingsCategories> settingsAdapter;
private int numCategories;
String[] CategoryArray = new String[] {"Privacy and Security","Account","Networks","Camera Options","Storage","Accesibility","Features"};
int[] resIds = new int[] {R.drawable.security_settings_icon,R.drawable.account_settings_icon,
        R.drawable.network_settings_icon,R.drawable.camera_settings_icon,R.drawable.storage_settings_icon,
        R.drawable.accessibility_settings_icon,R.drawable.feature_settings_icon,};
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View settingsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);
    settingsList = (ListView)settingsView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // initialize the items list
   return settingsView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
    settingsList = getListView();
    settingsList.setDivider(null);
    mItems = new ArrayList<SettingsCategories>();
    Resources resources = getResources();

    for(int c = 0; c < numCategories; c++)
    {
        mItems.add(new SettingsCategories(CategoryArray[c],resIds[c]));
    }

   // initialize and set the list adapter
    // settingsAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(this.getActivity(), mItems);

    setListAdapter(new SettingsAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
    settingsList.setAdapter(settingsAdapter);

}

public Settings()
{

  this.numCategories = CategoryArray.length;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Object i = l.getItemAtPosition(position);
}

public class SettingsCategories
{
  private String settingText;
  private int imgResId;

    SettingsCategories(String settingText,int imgResId)
  {
     this.settingText = settingText;
     this.imgResId = imgResId;
  }

   public String getSettingText()
    {
        return this.settingText;
    }
    public int getImgResId()
    {
        return this.imgResId;
    }
 }
}
```

and finally these are my xml layouts (the first one is the main view and the second one is the view of a single item in the list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchFunction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</SearchView>

 <ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </ListView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

this represents an individual item in the list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="52dp"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:id="@+id/settingCategoryImg"
 />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="52dp"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/settingCategoryName"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/settingCategoryImg"
 />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: remove `settingsList = getListView();` i think your problem will be solved as you initialized that in `onCreateView` , check `numCategories` too in `onViewCreated`,

Comment: Put Logs step by step. May you will found silly mistake.

Comment: no I'm afraid I tried everything except for what fell in love said I guess I'll do what he said and that is to put bps everywhere. I'm really sorry about the late reply I've never had anyone reply to me this late in the morning before so I figured I could just go away for a half hour.

Comment: I re-read nonames post and it turns out by doing that one change in onViewCreated , solved it. Thanks No name and thanks everyone else who posted.  this line setListAdapter(new SettingsAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));  makes it not display anything but comment it out and use this settingsAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(this.getActivity(), mItems); instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting null adapter so it is not refreshing.
you are commented initialization part

check in the following method:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
    settingsList = getListView();
    settingsList.setDivider(null);
    mItems = new ArrayList<SettingsCategories>();
    Resources resources = getResources();

    for(int c = 0; c < numCategories; c++)
    {
        mItems.add(new SettingsCategories(CategoryArray[c],resIds[c]));
    }

   // initialize and set the list adapter
    // settingsAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(this.getActivity(), mItems);

    setListAdapter(new SettingsAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
    settingsList.setAdapter(settingsAdapter);

}
```

Your are using ListFragement and again inflating layout. that is not a good idea. when you are extending listfragment then inflating the layout is not required and  and modify above method like:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
  // remove the dividers from the ListView of the ListFragment
    settingsList = getListView();
    settingsList.setDivider(null);
    mItems = new ArrayList<SettingsCategories>();
    Resources resources = getResources();

    for(int c = 0; c < numCategories; c++)
    {
        mItems.add(new SettingsCategories(CategoryArray[c],resIds[c]));
    }

   // initialize and set the list adapter
     settingsAdapter = new SettingsAdapter(this.getActivity(), mItems);

    //setListAdapter(new SettingsAdapter(getActivity(), mItems));
    settingsList.setAdapter(settingsAdapter);

}
```